# Jenkins build a subfolder project

Tags: git, jenkins, gradle

In my git repository, there are few separate Java projects. In the Jenkins build task, I want to build only one of the projects in the git repository. As I see, the workspace is specified as the whole repository and build.gradle file is searched in the git repository root folder as workspace in the Jenkins build item. How can I specify the subfolder as the workspace? Or How can I build the subfolder project in the workspace in the Jenkins?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]HI ,

if you are using pipeline , just `sh 'cd project a'` and than build your gradle task.

if you are using gradle step Advanced --> Build File , and than add the relevant subfolder.

Comment: Thank you Mor Lajb, "Advanced --> Build File" option worked for me.